# ORACLE Flash Cache Hit % negative value in version 19C

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c, awr

I have an AWR report covering an issue of decreasing performance oracle 19C in the section of Instance Efficiency Percentages (Target 100%) I notice a negative value of Flash Cache Hit % comparing with other clients the normal value it is 100 or 0.
As motioned below in the screenshot when the issue:
[image]

Can you help me why this negative value appear?

Comment: please any help

Comment: Could be a bug, check with Oracle support. I found following that looks relevant, bug - 26986779

Comment: @Pankaj Thank you for you help but we have 19C version this bug fixed in Version 11.2.0.4

Comment: plz any other informations